# How do I make suffix function case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript, string

I'd like to make the following code case-insensitive. If I test it out with

```
isSuffix("Albatross", "Ross")
```

it returns false, but if I try

```
isSuffix("Albatross", "ross")
```

it returns true.

How do I make it case-insensitive?

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
  if (str.substring(str.length - suffix.length) == suffix) {
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: to make something case insensitive you could make both strings lowercase.  Use the str.toLowerCase(); function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this (which makes use of `.toLowerCase()`

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
    return (str.substring(str.length - suffix.length).toLowerCase() == suffix.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
    var regSuffix = new RegExp(suffix + '$', 'i');
    if ( regSuffix.test(str) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if the strings contain special characters?

Comment: if the input isn't sanitary then yes that could pose an issue

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `toLowerCase` function.

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    if (str.substring(str.length - suffix.length) == suffix.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.toLowerCase()`

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
if (str.substring(str.length - suffix.length).toLowerCase() == suffix.toLowerCase())
    return true;
return false;
}

alert(isSuffix("Albatross", "Ross"))
```

You could use a regular expression, too, but this is closer to your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can use case insensitive [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) match with "i" (when suffix is either just text or cost of escaping worth it) you have to convert strings to lower case first before searching. Depending on your operations per-converting one or both to lower case may give better performance if you need to perform a lot of searches.

Creating new string to simply check if suffix matches could also be wasteful. For ancient browsers you can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) after converting string to lower case with [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

For more modern JavaScript code (current versions of browsers/NodeJS) use [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) (the link also includes polyfill):

```
function isSuffix(str, suffix) {
   return (str.toLowerCase().endsWith(suffix.toLowerCase());
}
```